# Modify any element of the array

Tags: c, algorithm

Given an array of integers , you can modify any of a number of arbitrary positive integer , and ultimately makes the entire array is strictly increasing and are positive integers , and **asked at least need to change a few numbers**

input: 5 1 2 2 3 4

output: 3

and there is what i have tried ,Each number in order to reduce more a ( first number minus one , then the second number minus two ,the third number minus three)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int Modify_the_array(int B[],int n);
    int max(int a,int b);
    int main(int argc,char *argv) {

        int before_array[]={1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5};
        int len=sizeof(before_array[0])/sizeof(before_array);
        int b;
        b=Modify_the_array(before_array,len);
        printf("%d\n",b);
        return 0;
    }

    int max(int a,int b){
        return a>b?a:b;
    }

    int Modify_the_array(int B[],int len) {
        int i,b=0,n=1;
        int maxsofar,tmp,j;
        for (i=0;i<len;i++){
            B[i]=B[i]-n;
            n++;
         }

        maxsofar=0;
        tmp=0;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
            for (j=i+1;j<len;j++) {
            if (B[j]==B[i]&&B[i]>1) {
                maxsofar=max(maxsofar,++tmp);
                b=len-maxsofar;
            }
        }
    }
        return b;
}
```

somebody recommend there is another solution for this question,more efficently ,can anyone give me some advice,thank in advance

Comment: can't you sort the array?

Comment: Your example input/output is not clear to me. Can you show how you got 3 as the output?

Comment: I believe this is a sorting algorithm question thrown by a tutor. Probably wants to see which best sorting algorithm the student decides to implement, whether they considered stability, memory and  time complexity :)

Comment: If you can modify any element, what stops you from overwriting all values with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`?

Comment: @rurouni88 Sorting is just one step; making it strictly increasing requires another step.

Comment: for example ,i gave 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5 as Array a,and after opertation,it became 1,1,1,1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,the answer is the length of array minus (Do not drop the longest sequence length,all >0)@user1990169

Comment: `1,1,1,1,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3` is not strictly increasing ...

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem recently. To make clear:

**Problem Statement**

You are given a sequence of integers a1,a2,a3.....an. You are free to replace any integer with any other positive integer. How many integers must be replaced to make the resulting sequence strictly increasing?

**Input Format**

The first line of the test case contains an integer N - the number of entries in the sequence. 
The next line contains N space separated integers where the ith integer is ai.

**Output Format**

Output the minimal number of integers that should be replaced to make the sequence strictly increasing.

Given your input, `len = 5, arr = [1 2 2 3 4]`, after minus `index+1`, get `[0 0 -1 -1 -1]`.

Ignoring negative elements(these must be changed), compute [Longest Increasing Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)(nondecreasing for this problem), which is a classic Dynamic Programming problem.

Denote the length of LIS = n(these elements will not be changed). So the final answer(the part doesn't belong to the increasing subsequence and the ignored negative part) is `len-n`(5-2=3).

We can compute LIS in O(nlogn) time with O(n) space.

```
int solve(vector<int> &arr) {
    int len = arr.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] -= i+1;
    }
    vector<int> lis(len,0);
    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(arr[i] >= 0) {
            int pos = binarysearchPos(lis,n,arr[i]);
            lis[pos] = arr[i];
            if(n == pos)
                n++;
        }
    }
    return len-n;
}

int binarysearchPos(vector<int> &arr, int n, int target) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    if(arr[n-1] <= target)
        return n;
    int low = 0, high = n-1;
    while(low < high) {
        int mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(arr[mid] > target) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```